# How to parse out Lat/Long from a Java string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to break apart the following Lat/Long values from a String:

`25N078E` representing 00-90 north/south to 000-180 east/west.
I have the existing Pattern
`([\\d]){2}([NnSs]){1}[(\\d)]{3}([EeWw]){1}` which works, I tried using the `()` for grouping but didn't work.

Anyway, I'm trying to validate the four areas; degrees and directions so I need to break the input string apart according to this pattern but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: the groups must include the quantifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using your capturing groups wrong :

You can use the RegEx [`(\d{2})([NnSs])(\d{3})([EeWw])`](https://regex101.com/r/ZhOTzI/1)

- `(\d{2})` captures the first two digits
- `([NnSs])` captures your north or south
- `(\d{3})` captures the 3 other digits
- `([EeWw])` captures your east or west

Use `$1`, `$2`, `$3` or `$4` to get your results.

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/ZhOTzI/1)